# How to make a member function a friend function in this scenario?

Tags: c++, function, friend, incomplete-type

I am a bit confused about how to accomplish the following using friend functions.

Say I have a class A whose member function 'f' is to be declared friend to class B.

The normal solution would be this, as I understand:

Define class A with 'f' only being declared not defined

Define class B including friend declaration of 'f'

Define 'f'

Now, what if class A were to have data members which are of class type B or a container of B type elements, like vector < B >.

Forward declaring class B seems to work (i.e. no compiler warnings/errors) but i am not sure if it is legal as per C++11 standard. Also, such a solution won't allow me to use a constructor of class B to provide in-class initializer for class B type members of A.  What would be the best possible way to accomplish all of this in conformance to C++11?

I tried finding a solution from the standard itself but couldn't find mention of such a scenario. I'd be happy if someone could point me to it.

PS I am really a beginner, so please don't assume otherwise in your answers. I wouldn't mind detailed answers though:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the MSDN article about this issue: **[Class Member Functions and Classes as Friends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahhw8bzz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**

Basically what you need to do is have a class type `A` with a function `f()` , and then you declare in class type `B` that there exists a function `A::f()` which will be your friend.

The MSDN example shows this well:

```
class A {
public:
   int Func1( B& b );

private:
   int Func2( B& b );
};

class B {
private:
   int _b;

   // A::Func1 is a friend function to class B
   // so A::Func1 has access to all members of B
   friend int A::Func1( B& );
};

int A::Func1( B& b ) { return b._b; }   // OK
int A::Func2( B& b ) { return b._b; }   // C2248
```

Comment: But this example has class A with both Func1 and Func2 having parameters that are references to incomplete type class B. I know that we can have references/pointers to incomplete types as long as we don't dereference them. Also, we can use incomplete types as parameters/return type in function declarations. What I am confused about is can you have incomplete type members in a class, as long as you define the incomplete type before you actually create objects of such a class. In particluar, is a member like vector<T> where T is an incomplete type legal if you define T later on?

Comment: Class B is complete in this example. An incomplete type just can't be instantiated, because it is incomplete... (makes sense) ... but if you derive from it, and make the derived class complete, then you could cast it to the incomplete base class and use it as you would use any other class.

Comment: And this "incomplete" business is a whole new question which you should ask separately as a new stackoverflow question. I'm sure you'll get a good answer if you focus on the subject.